# Websocket (javascript) vs Silverlight (ruby, python, javascript, c# etc)?

Tags: javascript, html, silverlight, browser, websocket

Just for clarification, is the question: websocket vs silverlight?

Cause websocket is based on HTML enabling the web browser and web client to talk with each other live. Does this mean that developers cannot use Ruby/Python in client side, but only Javascript?

If I use Silverlight, then it seems possibly for developers to use Ruby/Python on both sides right?

So in short:

Websocket => Javascript

Silverlight => Ruby, Python, Javascript etc

Is this picture correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets) consists of parts: server and client. The server could be written in any language while the client is intended to be javascript. Using Ruby/Python on the client side is not possible unless you write a browser plugin capable of running this code (the way Silverlight does it).

Silverlight is .NET meaning that you could use any language capable of compiling into MSIL (C#, VB.NET, IronRuby, IronPython, ...) which will run inside the client browser using a plugin that needs to be installed.